# is there any way to setState more then one time in marko js widget?

Tags: javascript, node.js, marko

i am setting state on button click.
i.e. this.setState('array', array);

on first setState it affect on frontend side. but when i push more value to array and try to set state again to doesn't affect the state and frontend.

is there any way to setState over and over again and render the page again.

Answer (score 2):

[Marko Widgets](http://markojs.com/docs/marko-widgets/) only does a shallow comparison between the new state and the old state to determine if the UI component needs to be rerendered. That is, Marko Widgets will *not* do a deep comparison of the array to determine if the new array has new elements or different elements. A shallow comparison is done for performance reasons since it would often be too computationally expensive to do a deep comparison for every property that is part of a UI component's state.

**Solution 1**

The recommended strategy is to treat objects added to state as immutable. That is, instead of mutating the old array, you would, instead, create a new array with the additional element:

BAD:

```
var myArray = this.state.myArray;
myArray.push('foo');
this.setState('myArray', myArray); // No change since myArray === this.state.myArray
```

GOOD:

```
var myArray = this.state.myArray;
myArray = myArray.concat('foo'); // myArray !== this.state.myArray
this.setState('myArray', myArray);
```

**Solution 2**

Another option is to call `this.setStateDirty('myArray')` after mutating the array:

```
var myArray = this.state.myArray;
myArray.push('foo');
this.setStateDirty('myArray'); // Mark the object as being modified
```

More info:

- [Marko Widgets » JavaScript API » setStateDirty()](http://markojs.com/docs/marko-widgets/javascript-api/#setstatedirtyname-value)
- [Marko Widgets » JavaScript API » setState()](http://markojs.com/docs/marko-widgets/javascript-api/#setstatename-value)
- [Marko Blog » A Closer Look at Marko Widgets » How is component state managed?](http://markojs.com/blog/a-closer-look-at-marko-widgets/#how-is-component-state-managed)